# Is there an way to create an variable which is usable over multiple files (Node.JS)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

Im working on an discord bot and i have an restarted var which is false in default, if it is set to true it should print another message in my logs,
now is there an way to create an global variable

I have an bot.js in which i call my exported module (in another file in this case core.js restart and in restart i wanna set restarted to true, which then is used in my main again in bot.on("disconnect")

Comment: Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [make a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add part of your code to clarify your question and make it easy for someone to answer. The clearer the question, the better the answer

Comment: will do next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working thanks to djfdev's comment,
im exporting an function that changes the value of restared
and im importing that value in my core.js

```
//bot.js
module.exports= {
    changerestarted: function() {
            restarted = true
    }
}

//core.js
const main = require("../../bot.js")
const auth = require("../../auth/auth.json")
module.exports = { 
    restart: function (message, bot) {
        if (message.author.id == 141218912934166528 || message.author.id == 533665091468656650) {
            console.log(message.author.tag + ' restarted The bot')
            message.reply('You restarted the bot, wait a few seconds')
            bot.channels.get("593824605144088586").send(message.author.tag + ' restarted the bot')
            bot.channels.get("593824605144088586").send('---------------------------------------------------')
            main.changerestarted()
            bot.channels.get("593824605144088586").send('Restarting...')
                .then(msg => bot.destroy())
                .then(() => bot.login(auth.token));
        }
        else {
            message.reply('I´m sorry,:no_entry_sign: you don´t have the permssion to run this command :no_entry_sign:')
            console.log(message.author.tag + ' tried to use -restart')
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the variable to module.exports (in bot.js) so it is

```
module.exports = {whateveryouhadbefore, restarted}
```

then you access it (in core.js) with

```
const bot = require("./bot");

restarted = bot.restarted;
```

Comment: tried it, sadly didnt work core.js = (http://light-theme-hurts.my-ey.es/8PeG12C.png)
bot.js(http://light-theme-hurts.my-ey.es/AQNuMfi.png,http://light-theme-hurts.my-ey.es/9uhXUvv.png

Comment: just saw the edit, but can i edit variables which are exported ?, since i need to check the value of restarted in bot.js and change it in core,js

Comment: You might rethink your design. For example, keep the value of restarted as a property of the bot class, and define a method that can change its value. Then you can export the class or method to core.js and change it from there.